# Material UI renderToString sx property does nothing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Whenever I use sx on a component rendered to a string and then output using **dangerouslySetInnerHtml**, the styles inside of that sx prop do not take effect.

Below is an reproduced example of the issue:

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-engelbart-xv9j2l?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js%3A26%2C1

```
import * as React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
function BoxExample({ color }) {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        bgcolor: color,
      }}
    >
      <p>Content</p>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default function BasicButtons() {
  const badHtml = renderToString(<BoxExample color={"#01FF00"} />);
  return (
    <>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: badHtml }} />
      <BoxExample color={"#00B2FF"} />
      {/* <BoxExample color={"#01FF00"} /> */}
    </>
  );
}
```

if you uncomment the third BoxExample and refresh, both green boxes will have their background color.

Comment: you would need to set up an emotion cache for the stringified component, and then correctly output the css from the cache to the document

Answer (score 0):

It appears by playing with your sandbox that the CSS for the renderToString component is not generated or is not injected into the DOM.  When the third Box element is uncommented, that third Box causes the CSS to be generated and/or injected into the DOM so the renderAsSting component (which references the CSS element in both cases) finally has the CSS available to it.

Consider that `renderToString()` and `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` are both SCREAMING "do not do this".  These approaches are not following through the full React rendering pipeline, so it is not a surprise that the results are lack-luster and missing key elements that you would expect if the code had fully been rendered by React.

Comment: renderToString probably does not fire any effects, and that is most likely where the CSS is generated. Just a guess.